# Safari messes the design when zooming in/out

Tags: html, css, safari, zooming, slice

I have sliced a design (see the first psd [here](http://www.free-psd.com/white/53-free-white-template-1)) for my practice, and it works fine. But when I zoom-in in Safari the whole design gets messed up. I have fixed sizes of central rectangle which contains all elements of the site which remains the same after zooming in and text becomes bigger. (I think the original design dictates the rectangle to have fixed dimensions!)

The question is this, how can I make the text zoom in in Safari without messing the design,  and how professional it is if you have this type of problem? Should this problem be necessarily solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Would help to see the actual HTML/CSS. At the very least, please update with exactly _how_ zooming in Safari messes up the layout. Is it that the text gets too big and the rest of the design does not resize to match? If so, switching from pixels to em or percent values will definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use em units as em unit changes when the font is changed. Em is associated with the font size so it solves the problem.